# how to make a JavaScript regexbb look for the absence of an html attribute

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm using JavaScript to try and create a regular expression that will find (in an html file) all divs that don't have an onclick attribute.

Example:

This div should be ignored..

```
<div class="foo"
     id="bar"
     onclick="someFunction()>some text</div>
```

This div should be matched (because it doesn't contain an onclick attribute)..

```
<div class="foo"
     id="bar">some text</div>
```

I tried this but it doesn't work..

```
var pattern = /div[\s\w\n\=\(\)"]*(?!onclick)div[\s\w\n\=\(\)"]*">/
```

I'm guessing that the first part of my regular expression (before the negative look-ahead) is actually matching the negative look-ahead.

Can someone help? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). You can't match HTML with regex.

Comment: Could you not just use querySelector with an appropriate selector? You should always prefer direct node access instead of string based searches.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `querySelectorAll` instead? `div:not([onclick])` will select `<div>`s which do not have an `onclick` attribute.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div:not([onclick])')
  .forEach((div) => {
    console.log(div);
  });
```

```html
<div class="foo" id="bar" onclick="someFunction()">some text</div>
<div class="foo">some text 2</div>
```

If you only have a string and so can't use `querySelectorAll` on it directly, you can transform it into a document safely with `DOMParser`:

```js
const htmlText = `<div class="foo" id="bar" onclick="someFunction()">some text</div>
<div class="foo">some text 2</div>`;
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlText, 'text/html');

doc.querySelectorAll('div:not([onclick])')
  .forEach((div) => {
    console.log(div);
  });
```